# how to get discount rule and discount from cart programmatically?

Tags: magento-1.9, cart

Any one know how to get discount rule and discount from cart? See the pic

[image]

Can i get this from external script using cart object? This part of code generate the discount amount section:

```
public function renderTotal($total, $area = null, $colspan = 1)
{
    //if the code is "discount"
    $code = $total->getCode();

    if ($total->getAs()) {
        $code = $total->getAs();
    }
    return $this->_getTotalRenderer($code)
        ->setTotal($total)
        ->setColspan($colspan)
        ->setRenderingArea(is_null($area) ? -1 : $area)
        ->toHtml();
}
```

**Update**

```
try {
    $product_id = '907'; // Replace id with your product id
    $qty = '1'; // Replace qty with your qty
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
    $cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/cart');
    $cart->init();
    $cart->addProduct($product, array('qty' => $qty));
    $cart->save();
    Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->setCartWasUpdated(true);
    Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess('Product added successfully');

    $totals = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
    //work
    echo $totals['discount']->getValue()."<br>";

    $quote2 = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();

foreach ($quote2->getAllItems() as $item){
    //work
    $discountTotal += $item->getDiscountAmount();

}
echo $discountTotal."<br>";
```

The left question is how to get discount label?

Comment: What exactly you want? discount rule means exact condition ???

Comment: discount rule name, the discount amount. The selected text of the pic

Answer (score 1):

To get the different summs for the rules I implemented an observer and save the sums into the item:

```
<?php


class Project_AddRuleSpecificDiscountToItem_Model_Observer
{
    public function salesruleValidatorProcess(Varien_Event_Observer $event)
    {
        $item = $event->getItem();
        $discount = $item->getDiscountPerRule() ?: [];

        $discount[$event->getRule()->getId()] = array_merge(
            $event->getResult()->getData(), ['qty' => $event->getQty()]
        );

        $item->setDiscountPerRule($discount);
    }
}
```

And the config.xml part for it:

```
<frontend>
    <events>
        <salesrule_validator_process>
            <observers>
                <project_addrulespecificdiscounttoitem>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>project_addrulespecificdiscounttoitem/observer</class>
                    <method>salesruleValidatorProcess</method>
                </project_addrulespecificdiscounttoitem>
            </observers>
        </salesrule_validator_process>
    </events>
</frontend>
```